# Using react router without sacrificing performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React Router to manage the URLs of my webapp. This is what I have so far in `Routes.js`:

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/inicio" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/productos" component={Products} />
        <Route path="/la-empresa" component={LaEmpresa} />
        <Route path="/contacto" component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/servicios" component={Servicios} />
        <Route path="/prensa" component={Prensa} />
      </Switch>
      <WhatsappBtn />
      <Footer />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

As you can see, I'm rendering the navbar, footer and a whatsapp floating button in every page, and inside those goes the content. I thought that this was awesome, since I'm not loading those three every time the user goes to a different page, but I'm coming across this issue: When I visit a URL that does not correspond to any of the paths, I get those components anyways (which makes sense). I would like to display a 404 page instead.

How is this possible whithout sacrificing the performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply add another `<Route />` below the last route like this

```
<Route path='*' component={() => <h2>404 NOT FOUND</h2>} />
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

`<Route path="*" component={ErrorPage} />`

and then set `exact` on all other routes like so:

`<Route exact path="/some/other/path" component={OtherComponent} />`

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple Route without the path like this:

```
<Route component={404Page} />
```

This will show 404Page on every path which you dont specify.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a catch-all path at the end of your routes in order to render a 404 component for any unknown paths:

```
...
<Route exact path="/prensa" component={Prensa} />
<Route path="*" component={My404Component} />
```

It must be last, otherwise any route defined after it won't be considered

Comment: you should remove `exact` from the `path="*"`

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is to add a `AppContainer` which would render the passed component together with the NavBar, WhatsappBtn and Footer.
Then you can add a `path="/"` which would be the error page.

Performance is not an issue since your component will only be rendered if the path matches! And also only the first one to match will be rendered